# Is there a use for lazy evaluation of 'zero or one', i.e. double question marks in a regex?

Tags: regex

I am currently reading the Regular Expression Cookbook by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan. They mention that any quantifier can be made lazy by placing a `?` after it, so this includes the `?` quantifier, resulting in `??`. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any further mentioning of `??` in the book.

As far as I am understanding `x?` would match the character x zero times or once, but preferably once. `x??` matches x zero times or once as well, but would preferably match zero times where it can.

I played around a little at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), but did not come up with a situation where this difference actually mattered. Does `??` have any practical relevance in any regex flavor?

Comment: I have thought about this long time ago. I couldn't find a practical use-case. Let's see if someone could come up with one. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example an input of `x123`

Now test with regex:

```
(x??)(x*\d+)
```

You will get matched groups:

1. `""`
2. `"x123"`

Now test with regex:

```
(x?)(x*\d+)
```

You will get matched groups:

1. `"x"`
2. `"123"`

**[RegEx Demo for test case #1](http://regex101.com/r/vZ0bC0/1)**
**[RegEx Demo for test case #2](http://regex101.com/r/vZ0bC0/2)**

**By definition:**

- `x??` matches the character x between zero and one time, **as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]**
- `x?` matches the character x between zero and one time, **as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]**

Comment: +1 for showing examples of where the lazy `??` makes a difference. @timgeb something like `A??` allows you to match `A`, but **only if necessary for the rest of the pattern to succeed**

Comment: Thanks @zx81 for adding meaningful explanation to my answer.